# PHP retrieve inner HTML as string from URL using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, dom, cross-domain

I've been picking bits and pieces of code, you can see roughly what I'm trying to do, obviously this doesn't work and is utterly wrong:

```
<?php

$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');
$data = $dom->getElementById("profile_section_container");
$html = $data->saveHTML();
echo $html;

?>
```

Using a CURL call, I am able to retrieve the document URL source:

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

if ($contents) return $contents;
else return FALSE;
}

$f = curl_get_file_contents('http://example.com/'); 
echo $f;
```

So how can I use this now to instantiate a DOMDocument object in PHP and extract a node using **getElementById**

Comment: So what is the problem? What does not work? Any errors?

Comment: Please note that if your HTML does not contain a doctype declaration, then getElementById will always return null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code you will need to avoid any malformed HTML errors:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');
$data = $dom->getElementById("banner");
echo $data->nodeValue."\n"
```

To dump whole HTML source you can call:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: this solution is retrieving content, however I am losing all html tags in the source.

Comment: I didn't get it, where are loosing HTML tags? This code just gets a value of an DOM element with the given ID and prints its **text value**. Moreover you can dump whole HTML using `$dom->saveHTML();`.

Comment: please modify your source to represent this

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$f = curl_get_file_contents('http://example.com/')

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($f);
$data = $dom->getElementById("profile_section_container");
$html = $dom->saveHTML($data);
echo $html;

?>
```

It would help if you provided the example html.

Comment: using this code, i recieve the error:

DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : script in http://example.com.

However, I can not disclose URL.

Comment: Per your updates: 
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : script in Entity, line: 19

Comment: loadhtmlfile is not now in my code. I was just pointing out that saveHTML() accepts an optional parameter to limit it to a specific domnode. saveHTML() should be called from the DOMDocument, with the domnode you want to save as the optional parameter.

Comment: if you can't give url, can you post html in pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but i remember once i wanted to use this i was unbale to load some external url as file because the php.ini directve [allow-url-fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) was set to off ...

So check your pnp.ini or try to open url with fopen to see if you can read the url as a file

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents(url);
var_dump($f); // just to see the content
?>
```

Regards;

mimiz

Comment: see edits bc im using a curl call to retrieve string successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');
$data = $dom->getElementById("profile_section_container")->item(0);
$html = $data->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

Comment: see edits bc im using a curl call to retrieve string successfully.

Answer (score 0):

i think that now you can use [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
  Maybe you should try Doctype existence (with a regexp) and then add it if necessary, for being sure to have it declare ...
  Regards

Mimiz

Comment: how would i go about doing this?